# "The initialization of the persistence layer failed" for the RES console of the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When I open the Rule Execution Server console for the Business Rules service instance on Bluemix, I get this error:

> The initialization of the persistence layer failed. Unexpected
>   exception during the build of DAO "persistence". null Cannot
>   connect to the database. [jcc][t4][2013][11249][4.17.29] Connection
>   authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID or Password invalid.
>   ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 28000, Error
>   Code = -4,214 ilog.rules.res.console.IlrConsoleException: The
>   initialization of the persistence layer failed. at
>   ilog.rules.res.console.util.IlrModelManager.createResourceProviders(IlrModelManager.java:376)
>   at
>   ilog.rules.res.console.util.IlrModelManager.init(IlrModelManager.java:143)
>   at
>   ilog.rules.res.console.util.IlrConsoleInitializer.consoleInitialized(IlrConsoleInitializer.java:86)
>   at t ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty the cache and refresh. If you still face the same issue, contact Bluemix support at http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and provide them with your Business Rules service instance ID.